# AssertionError: Timed out retrying after 4000ms: Expected to find element: `//*[@id="nav-link-accountList-nav-line-1"]`, but never found it

Tags: automation, cypress

**LoginPage.js**

```
class Login{

    elements = 
    verifyUserName(verifyUserName){
        this.elements.verifyLogin().should('have.text',verifyUserName);
    }

}
//export default Login;
export default new Login();
```

**LoginTest.cy.js**

```
import Login from "../PageObjects/LoginPage";

describe('Page Object Model Pattern in Cypress', () => {
    
    beforeEach(() => {
        cy.visit('/') 
    });

    it('Should Login to Home Page Test', () => {
        
        cy.fixture('testData').then((data) => {
            Login.verifyUserName(data.expectedusername)    
        })
        
    })
})
```

**HTML of the element-**

```
<span id="nav-link-accountList-nav-line-1" class="nav-line-1 nav-progressive-content">Hello, S*****N</span>
```

When I'm trying to run these two files in cypress getting assertion error

"assertexpected <span#nav-link-accountList-nav-line-1.nav-line-1.nav-progressive-content> to have text Hello, S****N".
Basically it's fetching the id & class and asserting with the expected text. Can anyone please suggest any solutions? TIA`your text`

Answer (score -1):

I understood that you need to grab text of an element and assert that grabbed text is equal to some expected text.

```
  //grabbed element via Id and saved into $ele using .then command
        cy.get("#nav-link-accountList-nav-line-1").then(($ele) => {
    //grabbed text value of the element in const txtvalue
        const txtValue = $ele.text()
   //did chai assertion to be equal to expected text
        expect(txtValue).to.be.eq("Hello, S*****N")}
```

Comment: I'm okay being given negative points but reason for this must be provided to give a chance of improvement. Thanks.